# How to properly have a autocomplete search input with multiple filters?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a context where there is a conferences table that stores the conferences. The conference table has a column "name" and also a column city".

I have an input type text and the user should be able to search for conference names but also for conferences that will happen in a specific city.

To explain better: The user enters "Ne" in the input text. So it should appear the results relative to conference names but also city names. If the user clicks in the name of a conference he should be redirected to the conference details page. If he clicks in a city should appear the conferences that have the clicked city as a value in the column "city" of the conferences table.

[image]

Do you know how this can be achieved? For now, is just working the part of appearing the conferences in the input search.

I created an AutocompleteController for this context:

```
class AutocompleteController extends Controller
{

    public function search(Request $request){
        $search = $request->term;
        $conferences = Conference::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->get();

        $data= [];
        foreach ($conferences as $key => $value){
            $data[] = ['id'=> $value->id, 'value' => $value->name . " " . $value->name];
        }
        return response($data);
    }
}
```

**Route to above method:**

```
Route::get('/autocomplete-search', 'AutocompleteController@search');
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
   source: "{{ URL::to('autocomplete-search') }}",
   minLength: 2,
   select:function(key, value)
   {
       console.log(value);
   }
});
```

**Search input:**

```
<div class="col col-md-6">
    <h4 class="text-white  text-center font-weight-bold">Search</h4>
    <form class="main-search">
        <input type="text" id="search" class="autocomplete dropdown-toggle" placeholder="Conference, Citiy, Category">
    </form>
</div>
```

Conferences table:

```
   conferences table

    id | name | city | ...

     1 |  New conference 1  | Newcastle
     2 |  New conference 2  | Newcastle
     3 |  old conference 1  | Bristol
     4 |  old conference 2  | Glasgow
```

Comment: Hi, could you please specify what exactly do you need help with? Are you having trouble with displaying grouped selection or with the redirection when option is selected?

Comment: Thanks. The part of the user write for example "Ne" and appear the conference with name like "Ne" is working fine. But Im not understanding how to add the part of when the user writes for example "Ne" and besides show the conference name like "Ne", that is already working with the code in the question, show also city names that belong to conferences that have the column "city" like "New".

Comment: What are your test values in db, at the moment of raising this question?

Comment: I update the question with the conferences table. If the user writes "Ne" it appears the first two records. But it doesn't appear the city "Newcastle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to search for cities and add category property to the data you are sending to your autocomplete.

I am not entirely familiar with database access so apology if bellow is not 100% correct.

```
class AutocompleteController extends Controller
{

    public function search(Request $request){
        $search = $request->term;
        $conferences = Conference::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->get();

        $cities = Conference::where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->get();

        $data= [];
        foreach ($conferences as $key => $value){
            $data[] = ['category'=> 'Conference', 'value' => $value->name, 'url' = 'conferenceUrl'];
        }

        foreach ($cities as $key => $value){
            $data[] = ['category'=> 'City', 'value' => $value->city, 'url' = 'cityUrl'];
        }
        return response($data);
    }
}
```

Then you will have to slightly alter autocomplete. For that you can use [category autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories) example.

```js
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
      _create: function() {
          this._super();
          this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
      },
      _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var that = this,
          currentCategory = "";
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
          var li;
          if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
            ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
            currentCategory = item.category;
          }
          li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );
          if ( item.category ) {
            li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label );
          }
        });
      }
    });


$("#autocomplete").catcomplete({
  source: [{
      value: "New conference abcd",
      label: "New conference abcd",
      url: "NewConferenceUrl",
      category: "Conference"
    },
    {
      value: "Newcastle",
      label: "Newcastle",
      url: "NewcastleUrl",
      category: "City"
    }
  ],
  select: function(event, ui) {
    console.log("Redirecting to " + ui.item.category + ": " + ui.item.url);
  }
});
```

```css
.ui-autocomplete-category {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: .2em .4em;
    margin: .8em 0 .2em;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<div>
  <input id="autocomplete">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know in the source how to have instead of test values have the values from laravel?

Comment: Replace it with your original snippet `source: "{{ URL::to('autocomplete-search') }}"`. As long as you alter your controller to include `category` it should display correctly. For actual redirect you will have to use `window.location.href = ui.item.url;` instead of `console.log(...`